# Can we use Using statement for objects which does not implement IDisposable

Tags: c#, .net

I have service which does not implement IDisposable in its class. While creating object for class, I putting object creation statement in Using statement. I executed the code, it not giving any error. Can you explain why the creation object which does not implement IDisposable not throwing exception in using statement.

Comment: Your base class would have implemented `IDisposable`. Post the code you're talking about.

Answer (score 5):

No. That is not possible.

If you use this code:

```
using (object o = new object())
{ }
```

You receive:

> 'object': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

The easy reason you won't see it implements `IDisposable` is that one of its base classes implements `IDisposable`.